# charAt cannot be resolved or is not a field. Did I missed some imports?

Tags: java

```
String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter String"); 
for(int x = 0 ; x <= word.length() ; x++) {
     for( ch = 'a' ; ch <= 'z' ; ch++) {
         num++;
         if(word.charAt[x].equalsIgnoreCase(ch)) {
               int z += num;
               num = 0; 
         }

     }
}
```

Comment: `int z += num;` This won't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`charAt` is a method. And method arguments are between parentheses, not brackets:

```
word.charAt(x)
```

It returns a char, which is a primitive type. And primitive types don't have methods. So `word.charAt(x).equalsIgnoreCase(ch)` won't compile. If you want methods on Character, wrap the primitive type into a Character:

```
char c = word.charAt(x)
Character character = Character.valueOf(c);
...
```

Comment: Upvote for providing more detail and improving on my own answer, which wouldn't have worked as-is.

Comment: Thanks.
Now I understand why it wont compile.

Answer (score 1):

[String#charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) is a method and hence should be written as `charAt(x)` not as `charAt[x]`

Answer (score 0):

`charAt` is a method, not an array. Where you have square brackets, they must be round brackets. E.g.:

```
if(word.charAt(x).equalsIgnoreCase(ch)) {
```

Comment: This won't compile - You *Cannot invoke equalsIgnoreCase(String) on the primitive type char*.

Comment: Noted - JB Nizet has provided the better answer.

Comment: You can still edit your answer and make it good - You were the first to note the problem, but there is another error that you missed.